# Windows Service does not start automaticall

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, service

I`m writing application, which based on QtService.
My problem is that the service is labeled "Auto Start" does not start automatically. In the registry  my service marked "Start: 000000002(2)"
What should be changed to automatically start the service? Or how I start this service from user (user rights account).
Sorry for my english.

Comment: When the machine is rebooted the service does not start?

Comment: Are the Qt dlls in the path that the service gets?

Comment: Service normally starting on command "net start FilterService"
By the way, it's mean what dlls in the path.